# Recursive merge sort in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to write a ruby method which performs a merge sort recursively. I have the method working, but It's one of those times where I accidentally got it working so I have no idea WHY it works, and would love to understand how the code I have written works. In psuedocode, the steps I followed look like this.

1. Split the original array of length n until I have n arrays of length 1
2. Merge and sort 2 arrays of length m at time to return an array of length m*2
3. Repeat the step above until I have a single now sorted array of length n

Basically what this looks like to me is a large tree branching out into n branches, with each branch containing an array of length 1. Then I need to take these n branches and somehow merge them back into a single branch within the method.

```
def merge_sort(arr)
  return arr if arr.length == 1
  merge(merge_sort(arr.slice(0, arr.length/2)), 
        merge_sort(arr.slice(arr.length/2, arr[-1])))
end

def merge(arr1, arr2)
  sorted = []
  begin
    less_than = arr1[0] <=> arr2[0]
    less_than = (arr1[0] == nil ? 1 : -1) if less_than == nil
    case less_than
    when -1  
      sorted << arr1[0]
      arr1 = arr1.drop(1)
    when 0
      sorted << arr1[0]
      sorted << arr2[0]
      arr1 = arr1.drop(1)
      arr2 = arr2.drop(1)
    when 1
      sorted << arr2[0]
      arr2 = arr2.drop(1)
    end
  end until (arr1.length == 0 && arr2.length == 0)
  sorted
end

merge_sort([1,6,3,8,22,3,11,24,54,68,79,80,98,65,46,76,53])

#Returns => [1, 3, 3, 6, 8, 11, 22, 24, 46, 53, 54, 65, 68, 76, 79, 80, 98]
```

The method I have actually correctly sorts the list, but I am not totally sure how the method combines each branch and then returns the sorted merged list, rather than just the first two length one arrays it combines.

Also, If anyone has ideas for how I can make the merge method prettier to look more like the ruby code I have grown to love please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my implementation of mergesort in Ruby

```
def mergesort(array)
  return array if array.length == 1
  middle = array.length / 2
  merge mergesort(array[0...middle]), mergesort(array[middle..-1])
end


def merge(left, right)
  result = []
  until left.length == 0 || right.length == 0 do
    result << (left.first <= right.first ? left.shift : right.shift)
  end
  result + left + right
end
```

As you can see, the `mergesort` method is basically the same as yours, and this is where the recursion occurs so that is what I will focus on.

First, you have your base case: `return array if array.length == 1`  This is what allows the recursion to work and not go on indefinitely.

Next, in my implementation I have defined a variable `middle` to represent the middle of the array: `middle = array.length / 2`

Finally, the third line is where all the work occurs: `merge mergesort(array[0...middle]), mergesort(array[middle..-1])`

What you are doing here is telling the merge method to merge the mergesorted left half with the mergesorted right half.

If you assume your input array is `[9, 1, 5, 4]` what you are saying is `merge mergesort([9, 1]), mergesort([5, 4])`.

In order to perform the merge, you first have to mergesort [9, 1] and mergesort [5, 4].  The recursion then becomes

```
merge((merge mergesort([9]), mergesort([1])), (merge mergesort([5]), mergesort([4])))
```

When we recurse again, the `mergesort([9])` has reached the base case and returns `[9]`.  Similarly, `mergesort([1])` has also reached the base case and returns `[1]`.  Now you can merge `[9]` and `[1]`.  The result of the merge is `[1, 9]`.

Now for the other side of the merge.  We have to figure out the result of `merge mergesort([5]), mergesort([4])` before we can merge it with `[1, 9]`.  Following the same procedure as the left side, we get to the base case of `[5]` and `[4]` and merge those to get `[4, 5]`.

Now we need to merge `[1, 9]` with `[4, 5]`.

1. On the first pass, `result` receives `1` because 1 <= 4.
2. On the next pass, we are working with `result = [1]`, `left = [9]`, and `right = [4, 5]`.  When we see if `left.first <= right.first` we see that it is false, so we return `right.shift`, or `4`.  Now `result = [1, 4]`.
3. On the third pass, we are working with `result = [1, 4]`, `left = [9]`, and `right = [5]`.  When we see if `left.first <= right.first` we see that it is false, so we return `right.shift`, or `5`.  Now `result = [1, 4, 5]`.
4. Here the loop ends because `right.length == 0`.
5. We simply concatenate `result + left + right` or `[1, 4, 5] + [9] + []`, which results in a sorted array.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer was exactly the explanation I was looking for. It really cleared up a lot about recursion for me, thank you again.

Comment: To properly handle empty arrays, you should change `return array if array.length == 1` to `return array if array.length <= 1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of a recursive merge_sort method for Ruby. Which does the exact same as above, but slightly different.

```
    def merge_sort(array)
        array.length <= 1 ? array : merge_helper(merge_sort(array[0...array.length / 2]), merge_sort(array[array.length / 2..-1]))
    end


    def merge_helper(left, right, merged = [])
        left.first <= right.first ? merged << left.shift : merged << right.shift until left.length < 1 || right.length < 1 
        merged + left + right
    end


p merge_sort([]) # => []
p merge_sort([20, 8]) # => [8, 20]
p merge_sort([16, 14, 11]) # => [11, 14, 16]
p merge_sort([18, 4, 7, 19, 17]) # => [4, 7, 17, 18, 19]
p merge_sort([10, 12, 15, 13, 16, 7, 19, 2]) # => [2, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 19]
p merge_sort([3, 14, 10, 8, 11, 7, 18, 17, 2, 5, 9, 20, 19]) # => [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```